# My application may be doing too much work on its main thread

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio

I'm a new Android Studio programmer and I have this error that make my app crash sometimes. I put 6 ImageView into a layout with 12 buttons and my app say "I/Choreographer: Skipped 699 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread." when I start the layout. How can I solve this? Heres the code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frappesbutton2"
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/buttonc2"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/buttonc2" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/frapeonemarco2"
        android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonc1"
        android:onClick="checkf1"
        android:text="@string/Check"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView2" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonA1"
        android:onClick="addf1"
        android:text="@string/Add_it"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonc1"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonc1"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonc1" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/frapeonemarco3"
        android:id="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonc1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonc1"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonc1"       />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonc2"
        android:onClick="checkf2"
        android:text="@string/Check"
        android:layout_above="@+id/buttonA2"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonA2"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonA2" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonA2"
        android:onClick="addf2"
        android:text="@string/Add_it"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonc1"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src= "@drawable/oreofrappe"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView2"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="37dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView4" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonc3"
        android:onClick="checkf3"
        android:text="@string/Check"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView3" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonA3"
        android:onClick="addf3"
        android:text="@string/Add_it"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonc3"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView4"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView4" />
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/frappeoriginal3"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/buttonc3"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView3"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView3"
        android:id="@+id/imageView5" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonc4"
        android:onClick="checkf4"
        android:text="@string/Check"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonA4"
        android:onClick="addf4"
        android:text="@string/Add_it"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonc4"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView5" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="150dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="@drawable/frappesbutton"

        android:layout_marginTop="22dp"
        android:id="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/imageView5" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/firstcoffee"

        android:id="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_below="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="27dp" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonc5"
        android:onClick="checkc1"
        android:text="@string/Check"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imageView6"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/imageView5"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/imageView5" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonA5"
        android:onClick="addc1"
        android:text="@string/Add_it"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonc5"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/buttonc5"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/buttonc5" />





    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:src="@drawable/segundocafe"
        android:id="@+id/imageView8"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/buttonc5"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/buttonc5" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonc6"
        android:onClick="checkc2"
        android:text="@string/Check"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/buttonc5"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/buttonc5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="80dp"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:id="@+id/buttonA6"
        android:onClick="addc1"
        android:text="@string/Add_it"
        android:layout_below="@+id/buttonc5"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView7"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView7" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

This is what I want to do: 
[Emulator Preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QmW60.png)

App run but is slow and It may crash.

Comment: post the activity code please

Comment: It may crash OR it is crashing ? What do you get in stack trace if it crashes ? Also it is not clear if you are doing any long running tasks which makes your UI stuck ? Please elaborate more about what are the inputs and data structures you are using ? Are you sending/receiving data to the server ? OR you are saving it to the Database ?

Comment: I dont have any activity code, its just the layout, it run but sometimes it crash, I have an launcher activity with an intent to the layout with the images but it take too long to load and sometimes it crash

Comment: [Link] (https://mega.nz/#!JsIE2KbZ!wtswA_biK4nWUVD1yZWkAbtu52gLnvX3wbfPdK4_yQg) Heres the app ZIP

Comment: 699 frames of delay @ 60fps means that your application was unresponsive for over 11 seconds. You're *definitely* doing too much on the main thread. If you don't have any other code running (in your onCreate/onStart/onResume), I would guess that the long load time is caused by loading your images. Are they large? Anyway, you should be able to find some details using [systrace](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/systrace.html) (I recommend using the tags `gfx input view am wm res dalvik sched`).

Comment: My images are 1075x1075 most of them png

Comment: That's pretty big. PNG decoding is slower than JPG decoding (it's not hardware-accelerated). You should move the photo-type content into JPGs, and just use PNG for smaller graphics, combining the two in views rather than in raw image data.

Comment: @SnildDolkow I already reduce my images to 296x296, What resolution should i use? And what do you mean with combining the two in views? Im pretty new on this

Comment: Some of your images are a combination of a photo and a border/logo. You should have *just* the photo in a JPG, and add the border within your Android views.

Comment: I ran a systrace on the app you posted. As an example, res/drawable/frapeonemarco2.png took 360 ms to load. The app crashed with an OutOfMemoryError before everything was loaded -- probably because my device has a lower heap limit than yours.

Comment: I already change the size and the format but now it give me this error : :res\drawable\firstcoffee.png:0: error: Resource entry firstcoffee is already defined.
res\drawable\fondocafe.png:0: error: Resource entry fondocafe is already defined.
res\drawable\firstcoffee.jpg:0: Originally defined here.
res\drawable\fondocafe.jpg:0: Originally defined here.

Comment: @SnildDolkow Thanks dude, My app is running pretty well now, The pictures seems to be too big

Answer (score 1):

Maybe your images size are too big. Check their resolution and resize them if there are too big. Do not use more than 800*800 images and try to have diffrent images for diffrent devices by putting suitable image at the right drawable folder.

Answer (score -1):

Try :

```
<application
    android:largeHeap="true"
    tools:replace="android:theme,android:icon" >
```

And
Put `drawable` in every `drawable` folder. Don't only put drawable in  `drawable-xhdpi` or other.Put drawable in `drawable-xhdpi` `drawable-xxhdpi` `drawable-hdpi`.

Because if you have no drawable fit your phone. drawable will be scale and cast memory.